# Twitter card that links to progressive web app (PWA)

Tags: twitter, progressive-web-apps, twitter-card

is there a way to use twitter cards together with Progressive web apps? I would like to link the user from the card to my web app so he can install it.

I wanted to use summary card with big image but idk how i could add redirect to my app from there and i cannot use app card since its not an actual ios/android app.

Answer (score 1):

The app card is no longer valid (falls back to a summary card). Your options are really summary card or summary large image card here.

One thing you could do is to add a parameter to the link and detect whether the user-agent is Twitterbot (the Twitter card crawler agent that renders the card, in which case, return the card meta tags in the page header), or any other browser or app, in which case, return the installable PWA link. That might work.

Comment: Do you have an official source for the information that app cards arent't valid anymore?

Comment: There was no announcement as this happened without the Dev Rel team at Twitter (at that time) being informed. The documentation still (Feb 2023) lists App cards as existing, but I know that they stopped being rendered with App Store rich links somewhere in 2021 or 2022. The most official source of information I can offer is that I was there when it happened; I'm no longer there and cannot comment on the current functionality of cards.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's official documentation about the [app cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/overview/app-card) only mentions app stores from Apple and Google. So I think they do not support progressive web apps.